# Magento 2 update System Upgrade Status: Update pending

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade

I'm trying to update Magento from 2.1.4 to 2.1.6 using the browser updater.

When I start the upgrade I get the message:

*System Upgrade Status: Update pending*

Nothing happens even after waiting an hour. I tried pushing cron jobs through CLI at the same time but it doesn't help.

I've tried going to 2.1.5 first but same thing happens.

Could it be an issue with my cronjobs?

Current setup is:

***** /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php /home/jm/public_html/update/cron.php >> /home/jm/public_html/var/log/update.cron.log

***** /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php /home/jm/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home/jm/public_html/var/log/setup.cron.log

***** /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php /home/jm/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/jm/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update using composer as follows. Run commands from Magento 2 root directory.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 --no-update

composer update

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: How can i solve this error : https://snag.gy/t5vcf0.jpg